# Python, Writing the file twice

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get my code so it will update Y7,Set1.txt but it keeps writing the data inside it again, + my new data that was added.
My code below:

```
print("Registration System")
print("Make sure their is atleast one name in register!")
password = ("admin")
check = input("The Administration Password is: ")
if check == password:
    input("Enter any key to continue ")
    print("If their is no names in the register.txt\nThe script will stop working here!")
    set1 = list()
    set2 = list()
    set3 = list()
    set4 = list()
    set5 = list()
    with open("register.txt", "r") as register:
        registers = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in register]
        for pop in registers:
            print(pop)
            choice = input(
                'Where would you like it to go? (Enter 1 - set1, enter 2 - set2)')
            if choice == '1':
                set1.append(pop)
            elif choice == '2':
                set2.append(pop)
            elif choice == '3':
                set3.append(pop)
            elif choice == '4':
                set4.append(pop)
            elif choice == '5':
                set5.append(pop)
    with open("Y7,Set2.txt", "r") as Y7R:
        Y7 = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in Y7R]
        with open("Y7,Set2.txt", "w") as Y7Y:
            data = (str(Y7) + str(set2))
            Y7Y.writelines(data)
    with open("Y7,Set1.txt", "r") as d:
        Y7S = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in d]
        with open("Y7,Set1.txt", "w") as Y7D:
            data2 = str(Y7S) + str(set1)
            Y7D.writelines(data2)





else:
    print("Access Denied!")
```

However the text file keeps printing the previous values, + a lot of ///////
Anyway I can get my code just to add information to that file, without adding all the /// and previous names? Thanks!
What's happening in the file is:

```
['[\'[\\\'[\\\\\\\'[\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'[\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'[\\\\\\\
PaulBrennan\\\\\\\\\
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file with `"a"` mode. `"r"` mode is used when the file only needs to be read and `"w"` for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be erased).

```
open("Y7,Set2.txt", "a")
```

You can check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).